# How to create a ros2 package that can be found by cli?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, colcon, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get caught up on the latest and greatest now that an LTS release of ROS2 has come out. I'm currently trying to create a package in a ros2 overlay workspace and I'm having trouble getting the launch file up and running.

I'm used to ROS1 where I had a launch directory in my package which contained XML .launch files and as long as the package was built I could run `roslaunch package_name launch_file.launch`. I'm finding it to be not that straightforward in ROS2.

My package's structure is as follows where I have a containing folder called asar and in it:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── image_capture
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── image_capture
│   ├── launch
│   │   └── publish_one_image.py
│   ├── package.xml
│   └── src
│       └── run_publish_images.cpp
└── vision_pipeline
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── package.xml
```

So there are two packages in this folder and I'm focusing on the `image_capture` package right now.

I can call `colcon build` at the top of my workspace and it builds everything fine. If I run the resulting executable manually it publishes correctly (just having it publish strings as a proof of concept). However when I run `ros2 launch image_capture publish_one_image.py` I get an error back:

```
ssnover@styrka:~/dashing$ ros2 launch image_capture publish_one_image.py
Package 'image_capture' not found: "package 'image_capture' not found, searching: ['/home/ssnover/dashing/install/opencv_tests', '/home/ssnover/dashing/install/vision_opencv', '/home/ssnover/dashing/install/image_geometry', '/home/ssnover/dashing/install/examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber', '/home/ssnover/dashing/install/cv_bridge', '/opt/ros/dashing']"
```

Alright, so it's searching my workspace's install directories, and that list is generated by `source /home/ssnover/dashing/install/local_setup.bash` which is in bashrc file. I can see when I check in the install directory that a directory has been made called `asar` and there I can find the executable built by colcon under `asar/lib/image_capture` as well as some other shell files under asar. So colcon appears to be treating my package similarly to the others, but ros2 CLI can't find it.

Am I missing a step? Is my package file structure incorrect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325932/how-to-create-a-ros2-package-that-can-be-found-by-cli?/) by [ssnover95](https://answers.ros.org/users/42866/ssnover95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem lies in my addition of a CMakeLists.txt file to the top level of the `asar` directory. This was causing a directory `asar` to be created underneath my install folder. When I took that out, it was no longer created and `image_capture` was created directly under this folder instead. I'm now able to auto-complete the command `ros2 launch image_capture publish_one_image.py` without a problem!

I believe that what I was doing (having a top level CMake file with a few calls to add_subdirectory) was allowed in ROS1, but it appears that this causes problems when the src directory is parsed under colcon and ros2.

---

Originally posted by [ssnover95](https://answers.ros.org/users/42866/ssnover95/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ssnover95](https://answers.ros.org/users/42866/ssnover95/) on 2019-06-16**:
An unfortunate side-effect I've just realized is that CLion will have problems loading multiple packages into a single project, as it uses CMake files to parse the project.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-06-17**:
I think there is an assumption in colcon that once a package is found it will not contain more packages in its subfolders. It looks like the intention is two packages: `image_capture` and `vision_pipeline`, but the cmake file outside of both is tricking colon into thinking there is one plain cmake package in the `asar` folder.

Interestingly, looks like AWS Robomaker had the same experience: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/troubleshooting-colcon.html